# Stored Procedure inside Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `SP1` that executes another stored procedure `SP2` inside of it.

But, when I run query to create `SP1` I would like `SP2` to not be executed. `SP2` should be executed only when executing `SP1`.

Is this crazy or can be achieved in some way?

Thank you.

Comment: This is what happens anyway. SP2 Would not be executed when creating SP1, only when SP1 is executed.